# rzc discover exited with code -1073741819

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.4) fails to compile NET.ASP CORE project giving the following error:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.1.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(69,5): error : rzc discover exited with code -1073741819.

Comment: Look up that error code. I found multiple fixes, not sure which one will work for you. This one http://www.fixerrs.com/2015/08/file-system-error-1073741819.html mentions an issue with Sound Scheme

Answer (score 5):

The problem disappeared after running "Repair" for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by modifying the visual studio using **Visual Studio Installer**.

Use the following steps:

Step 1: On Installer Go to the **Individual Components** tab.

Step 2: Now check the checkbox  **.Net Core 2.2 Runtime**.

Step 3: then click on **Modify** button.

After that open your project and rebuild it.

[image]

Good Luck